# Update Not Updating

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I am attempting to update a table in SQL Server via my code.  I have stepped through the code, and all accurate and correct values appear to be passing.  Can someone look this over and tell me if I made a mistake somewhere?  Thanks in advance.

```
public static string Update()
{
   string connectionString = null;
   SqlConnection connection;
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
   string sql = null;
   connectionString = Connection.MyConnectionString.ConnectionStrings[0];
   connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   sql = "UPDATE tbl_Onsite SET Onsite = 'Yes' WHERE BoxNum = GlobalVariable.Variables.BoxNumber";
   try{
       connection.Open();
       adapter.UpdateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
       adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql;
       adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  } 
  catch(Exception ex){
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
  return null;
  }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't have value `GlobalVariable.Variables.BoxNumber` in your table.

Comment: If 'all correct values are passing', what is the value of `GlobalVariable.Variables.BoxNumber` when you step through the code?

Comment: @Habib you are correct -- that is not a field in the table, but a variable that is having a partname assigned to it during the code.

Comment: @Brian when I step thro and add a quick watch onto that variable, it doesn't actually show me anything it just shows class System.String

Comment: @user2932408, then you have to pass the value to your SQL query, *better use parameter*

Comment: Is GlobalVariable.Variables.BoxNumber a SQL Global Variable or a VB.NET GlobalVariable

Comment: You are getting System.String because thats what the variable SQL is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
sql = "UPDATE tbl_Onsite SET Onsite = 'Yes' WHERE BoxNum = " + GlobalVariable.Variables.BoxNumber;
```